# javascript runtime error: unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen postings for this errors in this forum, but I still cannot figure out where in my code that triggers the JavaScript error.  The call stack only shows angular.js code.  None of them is my code.  So it's very hard to pinpoint where things go wrong.  When I click continue, the main page of my app shows up, but none of the navigation links are navigable. Every link has the same url. "http://localhost:52334/myApp/#:".  My application is running on IIS Express.  There is a  in the _Layout.cshtml. Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may be possible that you are invoking some angularjs functions with a null object. With the above screen shots, no one can identify and tell you the root cause of the error. To begin with, use the Developer tools in IE/Chrome and debug your JS code and pin-point the line which throws this error

Comment: Please check if your jquery is loaded before angular script.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  My application works when I changed <base href="/myApp/" /> to <base href="/myApp" />.  or <base href="/" />.  However, I am not sure why this work and what to put in <base> specifically.  What is <base> is for?  On my development machine, I would use <base href="/">, but if the server IIS virtual directory is App1, should I change it to <base href="/App1"/> ?

Comment: <base> sets the base url. So every relative url, will become relative to the url you used in <base>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
Thank you for the response. My application works when I changed 
from <base href="/myApp/" />
to <base href="/myApp" /> or <base href="/" />.
```